# ¿Se pueden usar funciones de login fuera del functions.php en Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Para el formulario de login de Wordpress, tengo que usar funciones como:

```
function login_failed() {
  $login_page  = home_url( 'URL' );
  wp_redirect( $login_page . '?login=failed' );
  exit;
}
add_action( 'wp_login_failed', 'login_failed' );
```

Estas funciones se añaden al fichero 'functions.php' junto otras como 'redirect_login_page()', 'logout_page()', etc.

¿Existe la posibilidad de hacer añadirlas fuera de este fichero .php? Por ejemplo crear un fichero en la raíz de la carpeta de Wordpress y hacer ahí el fichero .php.

Comment: como poder se puede, cual sería el objetivo? por lo general el raíz se mantiene lo mas limpio posible y las customizaciones van en un theme o child theme

Comment: El objetivo es crear un login nuevo, y que este, dependiendo del usuario se loguee en un sitio u otro. 
La otra manera supongo que sería crear un plugin que modifique el functions.php de cada uno de los sitios que administre, y que añada las funciones que necesito (las nombradas).

Comment: diferentes carpetas? diferentes dominios? base de datos? mismo server? que pasa si un usuario existe en ambos sites?